# Can I set up an iPhone 6 to use Bluetooth or speaker but never the earpiece by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, accessibility

My father-in-law has an iPhone 6 running iOS 11.4.1. It's connected via Bluetooth to a home phone system with several handsets throughout his house. He has hearing, mobility, and dexterity issues, so we would like to set up his devices to work as follows for incoming calls:

- if he picks up a handset from his home phone system, the iPhone should route the audio to Bluetooth;
- if he answers the call on his iPhone, it should automatically route the audio to the iPhone speaker (and not the earpiece).

As far as I can tell, the phone settings don't allow for this use case. If I set call audio routing to "Automatic", then the Bluetooth routing works, but calls answered on the phone are routed by default to the earpiece. My father-in-law cannot hear anything over the earpiece and it's very difficult for him to switch calls from the earpiece to the speaker. He often ends up hanging up out of frustration. On the other hand, if I set the routing to "Speaker", then if he answers a call using his home system, the call gets answered, but all audio is restricted to the iPhone. Unless he happens to be close to the iPhone, he can't hear or be heard on the call, making his home system useless.

Is there any way to set up the iPhone to work as we would like?